# VB delete last element in dynamic array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need a way to delete the last element in an array when I don't know how big the array is.

Basically I need the VB version of php array_pop, but nothing relevant seems to be appearing in
search results.

Comment: Why not use a `List(Of Type)` which is way more modern and easy to manipulate (LINQ etc...)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use

```
Redim Preserve MyArray (UBound(MyArray) - 1)
```

Comment: I think that's the solution ...yes it is

Comment: @YsoL8 For VB6 it's not. The lower bound will be lost, and you'll get a runtime error. Please retag your question to clarify VB version.

Comment: @GSerg: are you sure? I'm using this code for changing array length exactly in vb6 and have never faced the situation when lower array bound differs from 0

Comment: @GSerg vb.net. At least that's on the course documentation :)

Comment: Yes, I am. Try: `Dim arr() As Long : ReDim arr(1 To 10) : ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)`. Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range. Of course, it'll work fine if the lower bound is `0`. But in VB6, it's often not. Which is a great, great thing.

Comment: @GSerg thanks a lot, your advice saved me after countless tries to find out why my ReDim is not working. Thought ReDim would determine the lower limit automatically, seems that that is not the case. First time using VBA in a while, still bugs me, that some functions return arrays which start with 1 instead of 0. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

VB6:

```
redim preserve arr(lbound(arr) to ubound(arr) - 1)
```

VB.NET:

```
redim preserve arr(arr.GetUpperBound(0) - 1)
```